# how can I open "Network" folder with applescript

Tags: macos, localization, applescript, finder

I have this script:

```
set filename to getLocalizedString("Finder", "AXICON5")
--set openIP to filename & PCIP
tell application "Finder" to activate
tell application "Finder"
      try
     --open folder openIP
     --on error errMsg number errNbr
     open folder filename
      end try
 tell application "Finder" to activate
end tell
on getLocalizedString(a, x)
     tell application a to return localized string x
end getLocalizedString
```

What I'm trying to do is open a folder in "Network" folder. If fail, open "Network" folder.
What's more, the app is localized with serval languages, so, I use the function getLocalizedString(a, x) to get the localizedString "network" from Finder.app.

Here comes the problem. Some languages have no case-sensitive problem, like Chinese, Japanese. But in English, I get the string "network", and I can't go to the folder. "Network" works fine.
Plz help!

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://yournetworkfolderaddress/foldersname"
end tell
```

For example:

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://2TB._smb._tcp.local/Volume_1"
end tell
```

Comment: You're required to elaborate on an answer along with the code on Stack Overflow. Just some explanation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution .I use 
tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using {shift down, command down}
    end tell
to go to network folder and get the title of it.Then I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused... the Network folder lists shared network resources that you can connect to. You don't "open" a network folder, you mount the volume and then open a folder on the mounted volume. I've never tried to open a folder in the Network folder. So I'm confused what you're trying to do.

In any case, regarding the localized string issue I'm not seeing it. First let me tell you that the Finder does not have a "localized string" command; it's an applescript command... so you should not be telling the Finder to get a localized string. Second, I'm english and when I get the localized string of "Network" it is capitalized so I'm not sure why you are getting a lower case "n".

```
set folderName to "Network"
localized string folderName --> "Network"
```

So I'm confused about a couple things you're doing. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Hi,thx for paying attention to it.I have a application that can find some devices in my  local network.When I select the device ,I want to open the folder of the device in Network folder.As to the string ,because I have serval languages to localize,so I have to get the localized string of "network" using   this function   set filename to getLocalizedString("Finder", "AXICON5")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps.

To reveal the Network folder in a Finder window:

```
tell application "Finder" to reveal folder "Network" of computer container
```

To open the Network folder in a Finder window:

```
tell application "Finder" to open folder "Network" of computer container
```